Why is the last digit incorrect in my timing attack password cracker using Python?
I'm working on a timing attack to crack a password using Python. My goal is to measure the time it takes to check each digit of the password and use this information to deduce the correct digits. The code mostly works, but I often find that the last digit is not correct. Here is the code I have so far:
import time
real_password = "7090"

def check_password(password):  # Don't change
    if len(password) != len(real_password):
        return False

    for x, y in zip(password, real_password):
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulates the wait time of the safe's mechanism

        if int(x) != int(y):
            return False
    return True

def crack_password():
    password = ["0"] * len(real_password)

    for i in range(len(real_password)):
        max_time = 0
        correct_digit = 0

        for digit in range(10):
            password[i] = str(digit)
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            check_password("".join(password))
            end_time = time.perf_counter()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

            # Compare the elapsed time to find the maximum

            if elapsed_time > max_time:
                max_time = elapsed_time
                correct_digit = digit        

        # Set the found correct digit
        password[i] = str(correct_digit)

    return "".join(password)


print(crack_password())

QUESTIONS:

Why might the last digit not be correct in this timing attack?

How can I improve the accuracy of my timing measurements to ensure the correct password is found?


Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Attempts and Research:

I suspect that the timing measurements might not be accurate enough, especially for the last digit.

I've considered increasing the sleep time, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach.


Expected vs. Actual Results:

Expected: The function should correctly identify the password as 7090.
Actual: The last digit is often incorrect, leading to an incorrect password.


Does this password cracking algorithm actually require knowing the real password in order to crack the password?

@topsail No, the real password is only included here to simulate the checking mechanism. The purpose of the visible password is to inspect and understand the behavior of the code during the timing attack

To ensure that object creation / garbage collection do not mess with your timing measurements, avoid any object creation in the section you time. So move "".join(password) outside the timing-section and prevent any garbage collection in the section (if possible). Even better would be to remove any object creation from the entire loop.

An incorrect last digit and a correct last digit take almost the same time. They both have the same number of time.sleep(0.1) calls in their code path.

The timing you will get for checking the very last digit will not offer much direction, because the number of times that sleep has been executed will be equal whether or not you provided the correct digit. The loop will start all iterations in either case.
But there is another difference you can use for the last digit: the returned value! It is quite obvious once you see it, but you should exit immediately once you get a True as returned value:
            if check_password("".join(password)):
                return "".join(password)

And as suggested, it would be more reliable for your timing approach if you would perform the join before starting the timing:
            s = "".join(password)
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            if check_password(s):
                return s


So, with this code:
for x, y in zip(password, real_password):
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulates the wait time...

    if int(x) != int(y):
        return False

return True


If the password is correct, the execution time will be (just over) 0.1 * len(real_password) seconds.
If the password is utterly incorrect, the execution time will be 0.1 seconds.
If the password is correct except for the last character, the execution time will be 0.1 * len(real_password) seconds ie identical to the execution time when the password is correct.

Your code does not check the return value, it checks only the time. The reliable way would be to check the return value.
Alternatively, you could swap the statements in the loop.
for x, y in zip(password, real_password):
    if int(x) != int(y):
        return False

    time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulates the wait time...

return True

That way, the function exits as soon as an error is detected, so the execution time should be shorter if the last character is incorrect.

You could also put a longer sleep between the for-loop and return True if you want to measure for a substantial difference in wait times.
